# Callback for jQuery window.focus doesn't trigger after some time

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm facing this weird issue in Chrome. This is the simple code I tried (in my **web application**):

```
jQuery(window).focus(function() {
  console.log("Window is now active");
});
```

This works fine for some time.

**SCENARIO**

I opened 2 tabs with different links (Say gmail, stackoverflow, etc). Then I opened my **web application's** home page in 1 tab and opened some other page of same application in another tab (Total 4 tabs).

Now, when I switched between my application's tabs, it showed me the logger for some time. But, when I clicked other tab(say stackoverflow tab) and returned to my web app tab, then loggers between my web app tabs stopped.

No matter how many time I switch between my application's tabs, it never showed logger until refresh.

I'm aware that this may be a rare scenario, but I dearly need a solution from someone who might have faced this problem as well.

**Any suggestion about any plugin to be used is also welcome**

**EDIT**

Well now I got a hint of why this problem is happening, but haven't found any solution yet.

After following [THIS](http://greensock.com/forums/topic/9059-cross-browser-to-detect-tab-or-window-is-active-so-animations-stay-in-sync-using-html5-visibility-api/) example, I found that in chrome, you need to click inside the window after which focus event is fired, but not just on clicking the tab.

Comment: I think you (or another js library) just `$(window).off('focus')` at random time, without any event namespace or function provided. You should be able to see what is listening in chrome's debugger there is a tab "event listener" near element's style...

Comment: might be if you are logging the same message, the chrome console shows a counter besides the logged message. See if that is getting incremented. Or try changing the message by including a counter in the message.

Comment: @AnkitSaroch No, I'm aware of what you are saying, but thats not the issue